# Retrieve value from input to new input

Tags: html, onsubmit

I would like to retrieve an value from a different input to my button's input value.
I have an input, which is hidden and an input in which my costumers can change the value as they desire. I would like to retrieve this value and put into my hidden inputs value, when clicked on a button.

I've been adviced to use a OnSubmit code, but I'm not very familiar with it and can't seem to get it working, so I was hoping to meet someone who may help me.

The input in which I would like to retrieve the value from my other input is coded as shown:

> input type="hidden" name="quantity"

The input in which i would like to retrieve value FROM is coded as shown:

> INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="PROD_VK_1.4" SIZE=3 MAXLENGTH=3 value=1 onChange="CalculateTotal(this.form)"

Comment: document.getElementByName("PROD_VK_1.4").value.  You can set that as well as retrieve it.

Comment: It's getElementsByName, with an "s" after "Element" and, as Shadow has written, it returns a collection.  Easiest just to assign an ID to each form element.

Answer (score 0):

If both of the `<input>`s have `id`s, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('to').value = document.getElementById('from').value;
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/b2eDj/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve value from the above `input` tag using the js function `getElementsByName`
It returns a collection of elements of the `name` specified.So if there is only one element you can access as the zeroth element by accessing zeroth index as if it is an array.See the below example

```
var input_val = document.getElementsByName("PROD_VK_1.4")[0];
```

To put the value to the `hidden input` use the following code

```
document.getElementsByName("quantity")[0].value = input_val;
```

More on [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Answer (score 0):

You should have an ID attribute on your hidden variable; suppose it is `id="quantity"`. Also an ID attribute on the sending data will make things easier; make it "PROD_VK_1.4". Then, if you want the hidden variable to get a copy of the visible variable when the form is submitted, you'd code something like this:

`<form action="whatever" onsubmit="moveData();" >`

the moveData function would look something like this:

```
function moveData() {
  document.getElementById("quantity").value = 
      document.getElementById("PROD_VK_1.4").value;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but if there are no fumble-finger errors, it ought to work.

If you didn't want to hook this to the submit event, perhaps you could edit your question a bit.

I am curious... why do you want to do this when you could just use the value of the original input element when the form is submitted?

Comment: This worked amazing! Thanks alot!
It is due to my costumers being able to increase and deincrease the amount of quantities by some small buttons and therefor i would like it to link together